# ARC forbids explicit message send 'retain'

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am building ios app when I encountered a problem. It says ARC forbids explicit message send 'retain'. Here is my code that give me error.

```
    filePath= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]] retain];
```

What should I do here? My ARC is turn on and I want it to stay on so what will I do.

Comment: Do you understand what ARC is?

Comment: And also downvoted because there are multiple links in the related questions that already answer this.

Comment: I do not understand arc that's why I am asking. I'm new to ios folks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove retain and compiler will ensure that memory management is correct automatically:

```
filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
           [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
```